# How to run two or more topologies with the same APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want to run 2 topologies on same instance. 1 topology involves state store and other involves global store. How do I do this succesfully?

I have created 1 topic with 3 partitions and then added a state store in 1 topology and global store in 2nd topology.

Topology 1 :

```
    public void createTopology() {
    Topology topology = new Topology();

    topology.addSource("source", new KeyDeserializer(), new ValueDeserializer(), "topic1");
    topology.addProcessor("processor1", new CustomProcessorSupplier1(), "source");

    final KeyValueStoreBuilder<Bytes, byte[]> rStoreBuilder = new KeyValueStoreBuilder<>(new RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier("rstore"), Serdes.Bytes(), Serdes.ByteArray(), Time.SYSTEM);
    rStoreBuilder.withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());

    topology.addStateStore(rStoreBuilder, "processor1");

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream1");
    p.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaUtil.getBootStrapServers());
    p.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, KeySerde.class);
    p.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, ValueSerde.class);
    streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, p);
    streams.start();
}
```

Topology 2 :

```
public void createTopology() {
    Topology topology = new Topology();

    final KeyValueStoreBuilder<Bytes, byte[]> rStoreBuilder = new KeyValueStoreBuilder<>(new RocksDbKeyValueBytesStoreSupplier("rstoreg"), Serdes.Bytes(), Serdes.ByteArray(), Time.SYSTEM);
    rStoreBuilder.withLoggingDisabled();

    topology.addGlobalStore(rStoreBuilder, "globalprocessname", Serdes.Bytes().deserializer(), Serdes.ByteArray().deserializer(), "topic1", "processor2", new CustomProcessorSupplier1());

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream1");
    p.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaUtil.getBootStrapServers());
    p.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, KeySerde.class);
    p.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, ValueSerde.class);
    p.put(STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/tmp/" + System.getProperty("server.port"));
    streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, p);
    streams.start();
}
}
```

**When running single instance:-**

Expected:
Both state-store and global-store must contain all keys (data from all input partitions of topic1

Actual:
State store contains data from 2 partitions
Global store contains data from 1 partition

**When running 2 instances of this code:-**

Expected: Both global stores must contain all the data. 3 partitions are divided among 2 state stores and contain partial data

Actual: (S means statestore, G means global store, P means partition of input data)
S1 - P1
G1 - P2
S2 - P3
G2 - P1, P2, P3

Comment: Not sure I understand why you want two topologies, but probably having the same application_ID for both topologies is the reason why even with one instance you only have part of the data in the global store.

Comment: I am just in a POC phase as of now. I think same app ID causes same consumer group id for both stores. Any pointers as in how can I set consumer group id in my stores?

Comment: @R.B. You shouldn't use same application id for those two topologies. Try with different applicationId.

Comment: @wardziniak yes its working with different application IDs, I just need to know what happens in case of same application ID?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`. You use same for two different types of applications.

Value of `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG` is used as `group.id`. 
`group.id` is used for scaling application. If you have two instance of same application (with same `group.id`), they start processing messages from subset of partitions.

In your case you have two different applications but they used same `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`. For each of them subset of partitions is assign (App1: 2 partitions, App2: 1 partition) and they process only subset of whole message. It is Consumer group mechanizm.

More about Consumer group you can find:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-data-access-semantics-consumers-and-membership